# Laravel route Action not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

I am having trouble with Laravel routes. I'm trying to redirect to a controller after some middleware in the routes. But there is always this error.

The error is:

> InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 558: Action
>   App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@index not defined.

The route code is:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', ['middleware' => 'auth', function() {
    return Redirect::action('DashboardController@index', array('user' => \Auth::user()));
}]);
```

The controller:

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('dashboard')->with('user', \Auth::user());
    }
}
```

But the above code actually works (so I guess that the controller actually works):

```
Route::get('/testdashboard', [
    'uses' => 'DashboardController@index'
]);
```

So what is the problem? What is a valid route action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is might a better way to do it, change from

```
Route::get('/dashboard', ['middleware' => 'auth', function() {
  return Redirect::action('DashboardController@index', 
  array('user' =>      \Auth::user()));
}]);
```

to

```
Route::get('/', [
  'middleware' => 'auth',
  'uses' => 'DashboardController@index'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is rather a comment than a post, but I can't send it at this time. I don't undestand why do you pass parameter (`\Auth:user()`) to a method that doesn't require it (but it's correct when you do it for the `View`).

Anyways I suggest you to work on your Middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return redirect(...);
    } else {
        return redirect(...);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Oops. Sorry for that. That may be a mistake when I forged the code when asking. Since it does not actually runs I deleted it. I will modify it.

Comment: Nope! I add something more at my answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this route in place of your route and upgrade your Laravel Project to Laravel 8:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('daskboard');
});
```